# Windows Phone 8 ApplicationBar button long-tap event

Tags: windows-phone-8, application-bar

I'm trying to create a music player in my Windows Phone 8 application. I want to use same ApplicationBar buttons for Next and Forward as well as Previous and Backward functions.
Is there any chance to get long-tap event of an ApplicationBar button(?) so that I can differentiate Next/Forward functions.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Not a solution, just my personal preference and experience with UI design: implement a dedicated button for each function. It's quite easy for users to mis-tap (i.e. tap too long or too short) and cause an effect that is not easily undo-able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. The ApplicationBar API is quite restrictive, which is a deliberate move by Microsoft to ensure consistency. You cannot handle arbitrary events from the ApplicationBar. If you want this kind of behaviour, you will have to build your own UI to support it.

It is worth noting that your users will not expect 'long press' (more commonly referred to as tap-and-hold) behaviour on the app-bar.

Answer (score 0):

The ApplicationBar buttons only support a click event. It is not possible to detect a "long-tap".

As the ApplicationBar support up to 4 buttons you could use separate buttons. Alternatively create buttons on the actual page for this functionality. Then you can have as many as you want. (See Nokia Music, Last.FM or Pandora for examples of other music apps that have put buttons on the page.)